# Проблема с отправкой запроса через API а React

Tags: javascript, html, api, input, chatgpt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я взял API Chat-GPT с сервиса Rapid API, с помощью React написал код, отправляющий запросы и принимающий ответы. После отправки вопроса через инпут появляется ошибка(фото прилагается). Что является её причиной и как исправить неполадки?

```
function ChatGPT() {
    
    const pushData = (data) => {
        data.preventDefault()
        console.log(data.target[0].value)

        const answer = {
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages: [
                {
                    role: 'user',
                    content: data.target[0].value,
                }
            ]
        }
   
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': '1dc52d42abmsh2ef22411a18fd99p109471jsndb942c783796',
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'openai80.p.rapidapi.com'
        },
        
body: JSON.stringify(answer)
    };

    fetch('https://openai80.p.rapidapi.com/chat/completions', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
    
}
return (
    <>
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={pushData}>
    <input placeholder='Введите вопрос'/>
    <button type='dashed'>
        Отправить вопрос
    </button>
   </form>
    </div>
  
   </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум вот это: `model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo'` - не правильно. `gpt-3.5-turbo` - это тип модели, а тебе нужно создать объект модели под твой запрос, и использовать его id. Вот тут можешь прочитать как это сделать: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models/retrieve.